# Static website hosted in AWS S3 and CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have hosted Static website in AWS S3 and CloudFront. website contexts is multiple pages. I do have a problem with distribution. For example i do have have domain example.cloudfront.net when i am accessing it from this domain no problem i can go there and click on every page that i have lets say i am in a main page and i click about and domain automatically becomes example.cloudfront.net/about/ when i cope this path and paste it in a new page it gives

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
```

not sure what is the issue. Is there anyone who could help?
Thank you

Tried to give permission to access multiple folder inside of the bucket individually and also for whole bucket. Tried to recreate everything from scratch if I missed something but nothing helps. We can not make bucket public FYI

Comment: Maybe this is not your problem, but just to be sure, note, [you don't need to turn on static website hosting on your bucket for this configuration.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/)